# Windows Form VB.Net - Attaching empty Directories for Deployment

Tags: vb.net, winforms, powershell

I'm creating a GUI in order to launch a batch file which then kicks off a Powershell script. The GUI compiles fine and everything works great, however when I go to deploy the file it doesn't actually include any of the empty directories my script relies on.

How can I add empty directories to be included in my published VB form during install?

Comment: To create empty subfolders during deployment of your application is needed to know the tool used to deploy your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can always use the post build step to either create the directories you need or do other logic that your program may need such as run a batch file or power-shell script**

See the example below. It will create a directory Test in the output directory where the .exe is placed.

[image: Click the Compile- Build Events option under project properties]

---

[image: Enter the directory you need created]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. Why don't you just do

```
If Not Directory.Exists(dir) Then
    Directory.Create(dir)
End If
```

for each directory? I would create a list of directories over which to enumerate and run this each time the application is run.